# ShinyApps.io vs. Github

Tags: r, github, shiny

Instead of hosting my Shiny App on shinyapps.io, is there a way I can host it on github for free with unlimited hours?

If so, does anyone have resources to help me do this?

I really want to avoid paying $100/month for unlimited hours and just host my shiny app on github instead. The ultimate goal is to add a link to my shiny app on my website built in R (`rmarkdown::render_site()`). Thanks!

Comment: Github will allow for static render of html pages. For your app to run, you would need a server to support the app's functionality. The server should run R kernel integrated with your app. Github and Shinyapps.io are totally two different services meant to do totally two different things.

Comment: I don't think unlimited hours are available for free anywhere.

Comment: You can host on aws or digitalocean or a similar site for as low as $5/month with unlimited usage. But you cannot host shiny apps on GitHub

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Looking into it now. Do you have some links that you can share for someone who doesn't have that great of computer skills to host it on AWS or DigitalOcean?

Comment: Also, which one is $5/month? Very interested in this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way of hosting a shinny app for free that allows unlimited hours, as Dean Attal said in the comments [Digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/) is a good option but there are other option [Vultr](https://www.vultr.com/) gives more RAM for the same cost, also you can try with any VPS provider in  [Lowendstock](http://lowendstock.com/) are the cheapest VPS.

This [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) explain how to put a shinny server on a VPS.

Comment: Nice I didin't know about `Vultr`